# float in an object's message

Tags: objective-c

I have an object with a method that should take a float as a parameter, but the value in the object is not correct. Passing an int or double fixes the problem, but why doesn't float work?

Comment: You need to post the problem code.

Comment: Without any code it's hard to know.

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't provided a prototype for the method in the scope of the caller.

Comment: I have it defined in the interface of the object as a float, then I allocate the object in the view controller, where am I not providing a prototype?                                                   @interface WellPlan : UIView {

 float Depth;
 float Inclination;
 float Azimuth;
 
}

-(void)UpDateDepth:(float)DEPTH;

@end

Comment: @Peter: Are you including the interface header in the implementation of the caller?